# Set path in application.properties for folder in project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, path

In my project i download files to some directory that's defined in `application.properties`. 
I have such tree:

project

- img
- src

  - main

    - java
    - resources

      - application.properties

In `application.properties` i defined `upload.path = ../../img` but it's not working.
Is `application.properties` can work only with absolute path?

Comment: The `../..` is from the working directory and that is not your project directory. In a jar this would likely even fail, it is better/safer to use absolute paths.

Comment: Then better just to create folder in my code, using current application directory?

Comment: I'm not going to answer on that, as you might not have that access, it could run in a container which would have mounted volumes etc. etc.